# Replicate the behavior of ngModel inside a reactive form - Angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, ngmodel

I used ngModel to do a searchBox with a filter pipe and it worked well.

But this time, I want to use that searchBox inside a reactive form. It does not work as I have a big red error in console.

```
ERROR Error: 
  ngModel cannot be used to register form controls with a parent formGroupName or formArrayName directive.

  Option 1: Use formControlName instead of ngModel (reactive strategy):

  
<div [formGroup]="myGroup">
   <div formGroupName="person">
      <input formControlName="firstName">
   </div>
</div>

In your class:

this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
   person: new FormGroup({ firstName: new FormControl() })
});

  Option 2:  Update ngModel's parent be ngModelGroup (template-driven strategy):

  
<form>
   <div ngModelGroup="person">
      <input [(ngModel)]="person.name" name="firstName">
   </div>
</form>
at Function.formGroupNameException (forms.js:4939)
at NgModel._checkParentType (forms.js:5260)
at NgModel._checkForErrors (forms.js:5252)
at NgModel.ngOnChanges (forms.js:5193)
at NgModel.rememberChangeHistoryAndInvokeOnChangesHook (core.js:1506)
at callHook (core.js:2525)
at callHooks (core.js:2492)
at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.js:2443)
at selectIndexInternal (core.js:8396)
at Module.ɵɵadvance (core.js:8379)
```

When I move the searchbox outside the form, it works fine.

```
<div class="searchBox">
        <fa-icon [icon]="faSearch" size="1x"></fa-icon>
        <input type="search" placeholder="Rechercher une organisation" clrInput class="searchInput"
          [(ngModel)]="searchValue">
      </div>
```

I use the filter pipe like this :

```
<div *ngFor="let orga of (ListOrgaAndDoctors | filter:searchValue)">
          <clr-radio-wrapper>
            <input type="radio" clrRadio [value]="orga.id" name="orga" formControlName="orga" />
            <label>{{orga.name}}</label>
          </clr-radio-wrapper>
        </div>
```

How can I replicate the behavior of ngModel which send on real time the data to the variable "searchValue" wihtout using ngModel ?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `ngModel` in reactive forms. If you need to change the value in the form field dynamically - use the method `patchValue()`.

Docs: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#patchValue

Comment: In fact, I found the solution to my issue. I could use : [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" because I need one of the functionality of ngModel that it seems we can't have in a reactive form